# What is 'Musk' as used in this recipe

Tags: spices, language

I recently made [this truffle ravioli dish](https://forkandflower.com/index.php/2012/07/25/truffle-ravioli-with-beurre-noisette/), it was an easy enough recipe, but I was confused about one thing: it calls for 'musk'. I didn't know what this was, my research only turned up musk melon, which I think is probably different.  So, I skipped it.

So, my question is, what is 'musk' as used in this recipe, and what sort of flavor would it have imparted to the dish?

Comment: Just a lil' dash of Elon....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's nutmeg.

The author of that blog is from Switzerland, so I imagine that term is used there, but I had never heard used culinarily until now. I Googled ["Grated Musk"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=grated+musk), and still had to look around to be sure. Thanks for teaching me something.

**EDIT** As of an hour after the question was posted: Click the ["Grated Musk"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=grated+musk) link now! This question is now the top result :) You're famous, Tom!

Comment: I Googled that too - what'd you find that convinced you? The things saying nutmeg smells like musk?

Comment: @Jefromi The definition of nutmeg from the Free Dictionary, and the images.

Comment: @Jefromi And here we go: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nutmeg

Comment: That's kind of bizarre. It doesn't seem to be being used much of anywhere (that blog is the only usage I quickly found), and the OED (at least whatever part that's freely available) doesn't have it as a definition of musk. They don't usually have synonyms that obscure there!

Comment: @Jefromi I'm thinking the same thing, how weird, but I'm positive that we're right. :) I translated nutmeg into all of the official languages of Switzerland (except Romansh, Google doesn't do that one), and they all come back to variants of "musk".

Comment: Yup agreed it's right, just surprised it was in that thesaurus. I looked around on Google Books for a while and didn't really manage to find any usage that really looked like it meant nutmeg, and words that no one uses don't usually make it into dictionaries!

Comment: German native here: definitively nutmeg (=Muskat)

Comment: Just because it came up: Rumantsch Grischun (4th language in Switzerland): "nusch-mustgat". "nusch" is "nut" and "mustgat" is "Muskat" or the"-meg" in "nutmeg"

Comment: Awesome that this question is the top result. SE is definitely succeeding at making the internet a better place.

Comment: Muskatnuss, Herr Müller! Muskatnuss! :)

Answer (score 14):

I think it's nutmeg.

The author of that blog is from Switzerland, and nutmeg is *muscade* in French and *Muskat* in German. It's also something that'd taste fine in the dishes she uses it in.

Comment: Jinx, you owe me a coke!

Answer (score 2):

This is rather late in the discussion, but a recipe from Martha Washington's cookbook calls for "a little muske or ambergreece." Ambergris is from a sperm whale and similar in odor to musk. So, if it is an old recipe, it probably was musk from a deer.